# Android - How to save the state of a CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, save

I have an application with checkboxes, How can i save them?

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_linear"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Ontbijtkoek" android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Koekrepen" android:id="@+id/checkBox70" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Beschuit" android:id="@+id/checkBox69" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Chocolade" android:id="@+id/checkBox68" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Koekjes" android:id="@+id/checkBox67" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Brood" android:id="@+id/checkBox66" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Hagelslag puur" android:id="@+id/checkBox65" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Hagelslag mix" android:id="@+id/checkBox64" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Pindakaas" android:id="@+id/checkBox63" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Pasta" android:id="@+id/checkBox62" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Jam" android:id="@+id/checkBox61" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Thee" android:id="@+id/checkBox60" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Boter" android:id="@+id/checkBox59" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Smeerkaas" android:id="@+id/checkBox58" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Suiker" android:id="@+id/checkBox57" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Groente" android:id="@+id/checkBox56" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Fruit" android:id="@+id/checkBox55" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Aardappeltjes" android:id="@+id/checkBox54" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Zoutjes" android:id="@+id/checkBox53" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:textSize="30sp" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" android:text="Sapjes" android:id="@+id/checkBox52" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>     
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Yes i now, that are much checkboxes)

And my main.class is:

```
package com.boodschappen;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            showDialog(MENU_EXIT);

            super.onBackPressed();
    }

private static final int MENU_SAVE = 0;
private static final int MENU_DIALOG = 2;
private static final int MENU_EXIT = 3;
private static final int MENU_LOAD = 1;

CheckBox een, v52, v53, v54, v55, v56, v57, v58, v59, z60, z61, z62, z63, z64, z65, z66, z67, z68, z69, z70 ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);



    Typeface fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ankehand.ttf");

    TextView someText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    TextView someText52 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox52);
    TextView someText53 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox53);
    TextView someText54 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox54);
    TextView someText55 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox55);
    TextView someText56 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox56);
    TextView someText57 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox57);
    TextView someText58 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox58);
    TextView someText59 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox59);
    TextView someText60 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox60);
    TextView someText61 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox61);
    TextView someText62 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox62);
    TextView someText63 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox63);
    TextView someText64 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox64);
    TextView someText65 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox65);
    TextView someText66 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox66);
    TextView someText67 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox67);
    TextView someText68 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox68);
    TextView someText69 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox69);
    TextView someText70 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkBox70);

    someText1.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText52.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText53.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText54.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText55.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText56.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText57.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText58.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText59.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText60.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText61.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText62.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText63.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText64.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText65.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText66.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText67.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText68.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText69.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface
    someText70.setTypeface(fontFace);    // only typeface



    een = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
     een.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    een.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    een.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v42 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox52);
     v42.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v42.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v42.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v43 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox53);
     v43.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v43.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v43.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v44 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox54);
     v44.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v44.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v44.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v45 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox55);
     v45.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v45.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v45.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v46 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox56);
     v46.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v46.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v46.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v47 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox57);
     v47.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v47.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v47.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v48 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox58);
     v48.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v48.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v48.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v49 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox59);
     v49.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v49.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v49.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v50 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox60);
     v50.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v50.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v50.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v51 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox61);
     v51.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v51.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v51.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v52 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox62);
     v52.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v52.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v52.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v53 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox63);
     v53.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v53.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v53.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v54 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox64);
     v54.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v54.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v54.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v55 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox65);
     v55.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v55.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v55.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v56 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox66);
     v56.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v56.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v56.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v57 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox67);
     v57.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v57.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v57.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v58 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox68);
     v58.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v58.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v58.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     v59 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox69);
     v59.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    v59.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    v59.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
     z60 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox70);
     z60.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    z60.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                } else {
                    z60.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_SAVE, 0, "Opslaan");
    menu.add(1,MENU_LOAD, 1, "Laden");
    menu.add(2, MENU_DIALOG, 2, "About");
    menu.add(3, MENU_EXIT, 3, "Exit");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_SAVE:
        Here i want to Save the Checkboxes
        return true;
    case MENU_LOAD:
        Here i want to Load the Checkboxes
        return true;
    case MENU_DIALOG:
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(lidl.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("About");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

        //set up text
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Hallo, deze applicatie is een variant op Appie©. Deze applicatie is op volgorde van de winkel waar wij meestal onze boodschappen doen. Wilt u ook zo'n applicatie, ga dan naar het tabje Mail. Zet daarin welke winkel(s) het zijn, en wat u daar altijd koopt.");

        dialog.show();
        return true;
    case MENU_EXIT:
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Weet je zeker dat je wilt afsluiten?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        System.exit(0);
        }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Nee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //  Action for 'NO' Button
        dialog.cancel();
        }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        // Title for AlertDialog
        alert.setTitle("Exit");
        alert.show();

    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Do you now how to do this?

I hope you understand me, and i hope you could help me.

Gaauwe

EDIT:

Here is the code that i want to save things and load things:

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(2, MENU_SAVE, 2, "Save");
        menu.add(3, MENU_LOAD, 3, "Load");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_SAVE:
        Here save the checkboxes
        return true;
    case MENU_LOAD:
        Here load the checkboxes

    return true;
```

Comment: Check out this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/ You are going to have to play around with it a little bit, only way you are going to learn it.
This helped me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)? You can store and load the state and the name of the checkbox in a key:value format. [How to use](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). 
 
E. g. something like this:

```
// Init 
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mysettings", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

// Save
boolean checkBoxValue = v42.isChecked();        
        editor.putBoolean("v42", checkBoxValue);
        editor.commit();;

// Load
v42.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("v42", false));
```

However you should implement more efficient way, probably a loop through all the checkboxes to read its name or id, which you can call before leaving the activity.

Comment: I now that i must use sharedpreferences, but how, thats what i dont now, could you maybe post a example or just the code that i can use?

Comment: So i have an option with:case MENU_WEEK:
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   boolean checkBoxValue = v42.isChecked();        
         editor.putBoolean("v42", checkBoxValue);
         editor.commit();;
         return true;
  case MENU_LOAD:
   v42.setChecked() = settings.getBoolean("v42", false);
         return true; But then it says:   The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: My bad, `setChecked()` needs a boolean value as parameter. I've corrected the source above. P.S. You can initialize settings and editor objects once and use them for every occasion, i still recommend you to read the official reference.

Comment: i'm new to android, so maybe you would tell me how i can set this in an option menu, the save and load option menu, that i write in my description?

Comment: Are you stopped with helping me? :'(

Answer (score 2):

Override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and write which ones are checked into outState.  Then you can see which ones are checked when the activity is create by extracting that information from savedInstanceState passed to onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

For example,

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceStat(Bundle b){
    b.putBoolean("een",een.isChecked());
    b.putBoolean("v52",v52.isChecked());
    b.putBoolean("v53",v53.isChecked());

    // ... etc
}

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
   // everything you have in your onCreate implementation 

   een.setChecked(b.getBoolean("een"));
   v52.setChecked(b.getBoolean("v52"));
   v53.setChecked(b.getBoolean("v53"));

    // ... etc
}
```

IMPORTANT: There is no guarantee that 'onSaveInstanceState' will be called.  So only use this if saving the ui state is for convenience for the user and not vital to functionality.  User will be happier if you don't save data on their device, ie by using SharedPreference.

Comment: now that i must use sharedpreferences, but how, thats what i dont now, could you maybe post a example or just the code that i can use?

Comment: i'm new to android, so maybe you would tell me how i can set this in an option menu, the save and load option menu, that i write in my description?

Comment: are you stopped with helping me? :'(

Comment: In that case, @iDroid method is more appropriate.

Comment: But that i've also tried and that also doesn't work. Would you write the code that i have and put the code from iDroid in it? I hope you would do that for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save simple data across sessions take a look at the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html specifically the shared preferences boolean storage would do the trick.

On resume you should get the values from the shared prefs and set the checkboxes using them. On pause you should get the values from the check boxes and put them into the shared prefs.

I also ran into this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html when looking at the HeloViews tutorial.

Just some reading around, might get round to giving you some code examples if I have time later.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Heres the HelloViews tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#Checkbox

Comment: I now that but i've tried so many tings but i don't now how to get an sharedpreference for an checkbox, and if i have that i don't now how to put it in the code of my edit. So my question is, could you write an simple code for me?

Comment: I was writing a pice of code for you to do just that but i kept getting errors when using a checkbox's setChecked method, so I am a little stumped on this too. Will keep trying in my spare time though.

Comment: Oké, thats what im also have, maybe you could ask this question also, that more people see this question? I hope somebody could help me :'(