# Checkbox gets unchecked when closing the Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom dialog fragment with two checkboxes in my application, which sends value to the MainActivity using a Listener. The issue I face is that the checkboxes gets unchecked as soon as I touch outside the dialog fragment to dismiss it. I need to keep the checkboxes retain its state. Kindly help.

**TypeDialogFragment.java**

```
public class TypeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public interface OnInputListener{
    void sendInput(String input);
}

private static final String TAG = "TypeDialog";
public OnInputListener mOnInputListener;
CheckBox type1, type2;
View v;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    if (v != null) {
        if ((ViewGroup)v.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        return v;
    }

     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_type_dialog, container, false);
    type1=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    type2 =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3) ;



    type1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {

             mOnInputListener.sendInput("Type1");

            }
        }
    });

    type2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {

                mOnInputListener.sendInput("Type2");

            }
        }
    });

    // Do all the stuff to initialize your custom view
    // set "origin" to top left corner, so to speak
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);

    // after that, setting values for x and y works "naturally"
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.x = 20;
    params.y = 250;
    window.setAttributes(params);
    return v;
}

@Override 
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
    windowParams.dimAmount = 0.00f;
    windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(windowParams);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) getActivity();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use sharedPreferances to store checkbox value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800244/android-how-to-save-the-state-of-a-checkbox/6800323

Comment: You didn't post code that shows how you have the dialog close when you touch outside of it. Please post more code.

Comment: check this answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630594/9060917

Comment: @lionscribe I don't have a code to close the dialog fragment. This fragment is called in my Activity

Comment: @lionscribe What happens if I select main activity, how the dialog fragment is getting closed?